# Stack Exchange accounts overview does not count posts associated with accounts registered after migration

Tags: bug, user-accounts, stackexchange.com, migrated-questions

My [stackexchange.com profile, *accounts* tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/11921/daniel-beck?tab=accounts) shows no questions and answers on Programmers:

> [image: Programmers account, 141 reputation, 0 questions, 0 answers]

My [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/61386/daniel-beck) profile disagrees with that answer count:

> [image: 1 answer with 4 up votes, 141 reputation]

What's special about this answer is that **I didn't have an account on the site when the post was migrated** to Programmers.SE. My two answers on Server Fault are counted correctly, but they were migrated after I already had an account there.

Another example: [This user on Server Fault **only registered after his question was migrated** from SU](https://serverfault.com/users/134097/das7002), and his SE profile shows 0 questions on SF.

> [image: Screenshot of SF profile]
>
> [image: Screenshot of SE profile]

---

Posting a *question* on Programmers.SE didn't fix the wrong answer count on StackExchange.com.

[image: Screenshot]

I deleted the question and posted an *answer*, which fixed the answer count, increasing it from 0 to 2:

[image: Screenshot]

After deleting the additional answer, the answer count was correctly reduced from 2 to 1.

[image: Screenshot]

So **posting another post of the same kind will fix the issue for a specific user on a specific site**. The bug still exists though, and probably affects hundreds or thousands of users.

*My thanks to [Yannis Rizos ♦](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/25936/yannis-rizos), Programmers moderator, for allowing me to mess with his site!*

Comment: The Stack Exchange data is heavily cached and refreshed only when there are "reputation events", as the developers call them. If you will post new question or new answer, or even cast a vote the cache will probably be refreshed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The problem is not that the data is out of date, but that it *never* was correct in the first place, possibly because of an (implied) assumption that accounts always have 0 posts when registered.

Comment: Indeed, the bug exists - not doubting that - just explaining how to make the list refresh and show the real data. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Makes sense. I just wanted to prevent further responses like "It's just out of date because it's cached" by clarifying that *that* isn't the problem here. Also, I up voted the other user's question, now the SE profile shows **6 rep, 0 Q, 0 A** for SF; so rep caching is unrelated. And I don't want to post to Programmers.SE just to test other cache invalidation :-)

Comment: @DanielBeck Well, if it's for science I'll allow it (just flag after you post so I can delete...)

Comment: @YannisRizos Thanks. Deleted after a minute: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163376/this-question-will-self-destruct-shortly -- Did increase question count on SE, but didn't affect answer count. Now on to posting an answer...

Comment: @YannisRizos Answer posted and deleted here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159789/how-can-rotating-release-managers-improve-a-projects-velocity-and-stability

Comment: ..and finally it's there. Actually it's not really cache, it's simply a different database as far as I know, synchronized through certain events only.