# Answer count on meta mismatches network profile's answer count

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/221963/josh shows 1 answer for me on meta; https://stackexchange.com/users/204/josh?tab=accounts shows no answers for me on meta.

I recently (3/4 days ago) logged into meta for the first time in a *long* time, and my account was unified in with my other accounts.

[Merged accounts don't show correct post count on network profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134247/merged-accounts-dont-show-correct-post-count-on-network-profile) seems very similar; https://stackexchange.com/users/1389385/swilsonmcss reports no questions or answers (I think; that figure seems qualified) while https://superuser.com/users/127240/swilsonmcss reports one question and one answer.

There have been a number of why-is-my-question-count-zero bugs lodged, by they seem to be all caused by a one-off historic processing error.

This may be a duplicate of [Wrong question and answer count at Accounts tab on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132357/wrong-question-and-answer-count-at-accounts-tab-on-se) but the problem doesn't seem to be still occurring for that particular user.

**Edit:** Having now asked a question on meta, the question count went up on both pages.  The answer count is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

I read at [Stack Exchange accounts overview does not count posts associated with accounts registered after migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145714/stack-exchange-accounts-overview-does-not-count-posts-associated-with-accounts-r) that adding a post of the same type as is problematic (Question or Answer) fixes everything.

**Edit:** And it does. Totally a bug.